How to create an MS Dynamics connector
I have a service and I want to integrate it into MS Dynamics 365.
What I want my integration to accomplish is:

To have a configuration page where users can authenticate to my service and edit preferences
To add ribbon buttons that perform various tasks
I should be able to upload it to AppSource from where the users can add it to their dynamics environment.

Through research I've found out that to create integrations with Dynamics, plugins compiled to dll files are the way to go. But I'm unable to add ribbon buttons and a configuration page using that approach.
Please let me know if there is a method out there which allows me to accomplish these requirements.
Thanks
